# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'subdomain.domain.com'. You may need to add 'subdomain.domain.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django, nginx, django-urls, django-settings

after two days From deplyoing my application and working fine, I have decided to change the name of the subdomain so i have just rename it under the path:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available`

and then i have did again

`sudo certbot --nginx` for the "https" ,

then  adding this host in settings.py from my django application,

I have did `sudo systemctl restart nginx` to restart nginx

then:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

then

```
 python manage.py makemigrations
```

-->No changes detected

```
   python manage.py migrate
```

-->No changes detected

and when i go to the browser to access to my application I got this error

```
DisallowedHost at /

Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'subdomain.domain.com'. You may need to add 'subdomain.domain.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

, otherwise i Have added the host on "settings.py"

Help please isn't there any other step i should do when i change the host ,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not showed what you have inside your Django `settings.py` file, but I assume you have not configured the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable as you should have. This is how it should look like:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'subdomain.domain.com'
]
```

Also, make sure to restart the HTTP server. The settings file is loaded to memory, so if you make changes to it, you need to restart the server.

`systemctl restart gunicorn`

Comment: yeah in settings.py , I have already added it ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['domain.subdomain.com','www.domain.subdomain.com'] But it works when i have did sudo systemctl restart gunicorn now (The strange thing that I have did it already but it works now , I do no why....) anyway, Thanks.

Comment: I am glad it worked. :)